Translating between proofs in bounded arithmetic theories $\mathsf{V}^0$ and $\mathsf{T}_2(\alpha)$
Cook's theory $\mathsf{V}^0$ and the relativized Buss hierarchy $\mathsf{T}_2(\alpha)$ both have propositional translations to $\mathsf{AC}^0$-Frege. As well, both prove (different) formulations of the reflection principle for $\mathsf{AC}^0$-Frege. My question is, given a proof in $\mathsf{T}_2(\alpha)$ of some $\forall\Sigma^b_i(\alpha)$-sentence, how would one give a corresponding proof in $\mathsf{V}^0$?
To make this more formal, let me instantiate this with the weak pigeonhole principle $\mathsf{WPHP}^{2n}_n(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ specifies the pigeon oracle. From Maciel-Pitassi-Woods, we know $\mathsf{T}^2_2(\alpha)\vdash \mathsf{WPHP}^{2n}_n(\alpha)$. What formulation of the weak pigeonhole principle is $\mathsf{V}^0$ able to prove? In particular, can $\mathsf{V}^0 \vdash \mathsf{WPHP}^{2n}_n(f)$ for any $f\in\mathsf{FAC}^0$? If so, what does the proof look like in comparison to the $\mathsf{T}^2_2(\alpha)$ proof? I guess my confusion is in going from $\Sigma^b_i(\alpha)$-induction for arbitrary $i$ in the relativized Buss Hierarchy to just the use of $\Sigma^B_0$-comprehension in $\mathsf{V}^0$.

This won’t work. You’re forgetting that $\mathsf{V^0}$ translates to polynomial $\mathsf{AC}^0$-Frege proofs, whereas $\mathsf{T_2}(\alpha)$ to quasipolynomial $\mathsf{AC}^0$-Frege proofs. Indeed, you get $\mathsf{V^0}$ proofs from $\mathsf{I\Delta_0}(\alpha)$ proofs, while $\mathsf{T_2}(\alpha)$ only yields proofs in a quasipolynomial version of $\mathsf{V^0}$. Otherwise, this correspondence is pretty trivial: an $\mathsf{I\Delta_0}(\alpha)$ proof essentially already is a $\mathsf{V^0}$ proof, where you treat the numbers of $\mathsf{I\Delta_0}(\alpha)$ as referring to the ...

... unary number sort of $\mathsf{V^0}$, and you treat $\alpha$ as a free variable of the string sort. Actually, it appears you want $\alpha$ to be a function rather than a predicate; so translate it to a predicate first.

Note that it is an open problem whether $\mathsf{V^0}$ can prove WPHP, and whether there are polynomial-size $\mathsf{AC^0}$-Frege proofs of WPHP.

I see. Is there cryptographic evidence that $\mathsf{V}^0$ does not prove WPHP?
